# Is there a way to deploy statefulset first in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to make a kubernetes cluster to deploy first the statefulset and then all other deployments?
I'm working in GKE and I have a Redis pod which I want to get up and ready first because the other deployments depend on the connection to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [initcontainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in other deployments.Because init containers run to completion before any app containers start, init containers offer a mechanism to block or delay app container startup until a set of preconditions are met.
The init container can have a script which perform a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) of the redis pods.

Comment: To make this clearer, you don’t order the deployments. Both sets go out simultaneously and you wait on dependent services to be ready (either directly or via an excellent initContainer). This makes a much more reliable system.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got the idea, I just need to config a initContainers field in my manifest for the pods and think of a script or command that is checking if the Redis is up and running ....

Comment: With a distributed system, subject to the [fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing), applications need to be tolerant of the un/availability of services. In the above, your service would behave better if its readiness and startup (new in K8s 1.16) [probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) reported not ready when Redis is not available. This will help keep you away from the order of execution thinking on an asynchronous system.

Comment: This polling mechanism could be implemented out of k8s to avoid the injection of init containers if needed. One could `kubectl apply` the statefulset, wait for it to become ready by polling, and then `kubectl apply` the rest of the resources. Of course, the solution you have provided is simpler though.